# Java Compile Time error for instance level Final variables and not giving for method level local variables

Tags: java

Why is the java compiler not giving any compile time error for method level local final variables when we not initialize them?

( but it is giving en error for instance level final variables when they are not initialized ).

```
public class FinalKeyword
{
    final int j; // error: the blank final field j may not have been initialized.

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int k; // not giving any Compile time error!
    }
}
```

Comment: instance final variables need to be initialized from the constructor. block final variables can only be initialized once. so thats why you can leave them unitialized

Comment: If you would try to use final k, you would get "variable might not been initlized". Maybe it's waiting for initilising and watch that it's not using anywhere, that's why you havn't error.

Comment: For the record: if you feel inclined to, you can still accept the most helpful answer, even as the question was closed.

Answer (score 2):

Thing is: as soon as you change your `main()` method to

```
final int k;//Not Giving any Compile time error
System.out.println(k); //different story now!
```

You get an error about **k** not being initialized, too!

The point is:

- the compiler has to make sure that other source code that isn't visible right now ... is able to do a `new FinalKeyword()` without problems. Thus it can't allow you to keep `j` not initialized.
- but that `main()` method ... even when another method invokes this `main()` method - that is fine. The method does nothing! In other words - it is not a problem to define a variable that doesn't get used *within a method*! Because there is **no** way how you could get to that variable!

The compiler has to prevent you from getting into situations where you "stumble" over an uninitialized variable. When you invoke a method that has such variables ... but never uses them - that is simply a "don't care".

And surprise: when we go with

```
public class FinalTest {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    final int k;
  }
}
```

and compile that; and then we use javap to get to de-compiled byte code:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0: return
```

This is one of the rare occasions where javac does a bit of optimization - by simply throwing away unused variables. Bonus fun fact: even when changing my example to `k=5;` - you will find that the class file still only contains `return`!

Answer (score 0):

`j` is a field of the class. `k` is not. You need to initialise final fields in the class's constructor. Your class is using your default, implicit constructor which does no initialisation of fields.

The reason it doesn't give you a warning for the local variable is because you don't use it. If you were to use the uninitialised local variable, you *would* get an error:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final int k;
    if (k < 5) {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

As to why the compiler's not clever enough to know that you're not using the field either, I'm not sure. It's presumably more complex because of inheritance, access levels and such.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if the compiler comes across a situation where a `final` may be accessed while uninitialized, or set while initialized, there is an error.

A class's `final` fields *must* be initialized, because someone could access them at any time. If it is package-private, protected, or public, other code can directly access the field, and they expect it to be initialized. Even if the field is `private`, someone could reflect it and try to access it, so the compiler must not ignore it.

A method's `final` locals are internal to the method, and there is no way to reflect inside a *method* without modifying some bytecode, so the compiler does not need to be so strict. Instead, the compiler does control flow analysis to map out when the field will be assigned and won't be assigned, and it will throw an error if it is used while maybe unassigned, and will be content if it is never used or is used while definitely assigned.

```
void meth0() {
    final String s;
    // Compiler: s is never used; I don't care.
}

void meth1() {
  final String s;
  // s is definitely unassigned
  if(something()) {
      s = "something";
      // s is definitely assigned
      System.out.println(s);
  } else {
      // s is definitely unassigned
      s = "other";
      // s is definitely assigned
      System.out.println(s);
  }
  // if-branch def. assigns s, else-branch def. assigns s
  // Ergo: s is def. assigned
  somethingElse(s);
  // Compiler: control flow checks out; code is valid
}

void meth2() {
  final String s;
  // def. unass.
  if(something()) {
    s = "something";
    // def ass.
  }
  // s is in undetermined state
  // s = ""; // s may be assigned; error
  // use(s); // s may not be assigned; error
  // s is now totally unusable. Nice job breaking it, hero!
}
```